# Unable to execute Graphviz on a Mac

Tags: python, macos, path, graphviz

When I run the following python code

```
graph = graphviz.Source(dot_data)
display(graph)
```

I get the following error

```
  File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/graphviz/backend/execute.py:84 in run_check
    raise ExecutableNotFound(cmd) from e

ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute PosixPath('dot'), make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH

<graphviz.sources.Source at 0x7fc1511faa00>
```

When I check for Graphviz it does appear present and also appears to be in my $PATH

```
dot - graphviz version 2.40.1 (20161225.0304)
(base) jay@iMac-2019 ~ % echo $PATH
/Users/jay/usr/local/bin/dot:/Users/jay/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/jay/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/Users/jay/.pyenv/shims:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Applications/quarto/bin
(base) jay@iMac-2019 ~ %
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to install two packages (sadly both named Graphviz)
From the python library page (https://pypi.org/project/graphviz/)
**you also need to install Graphviz**
This page will tell you how to install the "real" Graphviz (non-Python library) https://graphviz.org/download/